# 3D tube plot in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

How can I have a "tube" plot in R? I have a dataset that contains x, y, z coordinates and a quimical component rate. There are 255 samples (id) and each of them may have different numbers of rows (observations/mesuraments). For each sample, I want to build a tube, however each section of each tube may have different colors according to its quimical component rate. In addition, the collor pallete should be in a gradient scale. The closet approach that I came up by searching about plots in R is the code below:

You can find my dataset [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gpqn497toafymy0/dataset.csv?dl=0)

```
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(dataset, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z,
             marker = list(color = ~Percent, colorscale = c('#FFE1A1', '#683531'), showscale = TRUE)) %>%
  add_markers() %>%
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'vector X'),
                      yaxis = list(title = 'vector Y'),
                      zaxis = list(title = 'vector Z')),
         annotations = list(
           x = 2,
           y = 1.05,
           text = 'vetor X1',
           xref = 'vetor Y1',
           yref = 'vetor Z1',
           showarrow = FALSE
         ))
```